# paper-select showing behind bsmodal in Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, drop-down-menu

I am rendering a form in a `bs-modal` where I have a paper-select with 5 items. When I click on the paper-select, the dropdown is appearing behind the `bs-modal` and is not useable.

I have attempted to give the specific paper-select a high `z-index` value, but it is still rendering behind the `bs-modal`.

How do I render a paper-select dropdown infront of a `bsmodal`?

Comment: Would be helpful if you could provide an Ember Twiddle to reproduce.

Comment: @jelhan I have not used Ember Twiddle before, is there a way to import BS or something similar? My BSmodal is not appearing.

Comment: You need to list your dependencies in `twiddle.json` similar to `ember-data` dependency which is there by default. Please find a simple Ember Twiddle using Ember Bootstrap here: https://ember-twiddle.com/32be824b0d6c5a585ad97e03c362cfc7?numColumns=2&openFiles=twiddle.json%2Ctemplates.application.hbs

Comment: @jelhan Thank you for the link! I am attempting to add ember paper as an addon, but in the console I am seeing that the request to get the `ember-paper` is being blocked by a CORS policy issue. Not entirely sure if I can get Ember Paper working in here.

Comment: Sorry missed that styles may be an important part for the reproduction. Ember Twiddle does not support sass yet. Therefore a [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) must be used. Tried to set one up but wasn't able to even use `bootstrap` and `ember-paper` styles together. Seems they have conflicting variable names. But maybe you could use it as a starting point? https://codesandbox.io/s/so-56484233-paper-select-inside-bs-modal-1yo1p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since **paper-select** is based on **power-select**, you have to set the property **renderInPlace** of your paper-select component to true to display it in place https://ember-power-select.com/docs/api-reference

```
<BsModalSimple>
  <PaperSelect @renderInPlace=true @label="Country" @options={{array "Morocco" "France"}} @selected={{userState}} @onChange={{action (mut userState)}} as |lang|>
    {{lang}}
  </PaperSelect>
</BsModalSimple>
```

Comment: This worked, thank you! I may need to add some CSS for positioning as the drop down so not appear near the initial component, but I am able to see it now. Cheers!